# How do you check the type of a local variable?

Tags: haskell, types, ghci

Simple question.  Is it possible to check the type of a variable that is only alive within a function?

For example:

```
main = do
       x <- something
```

How can I check the type of `x`?

I can't do `:type x` in ghci because `x` is not global.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Another way (quite similar to RobAgar's and hacky as well) is to explicitly specify some wrong type for the local variable in question, e.g.:

```
main = do
  x <- getArgs
  x :: () -- let's cast it to unit! ;)
  print $ head x
```

Then ghci will give us an error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `()' with actual type `[String]'
```

which shows that the actual type of "x" is [String].

Comment: Actually, assuming that `x` *doesn't* have the same monadic type as the do block, you don't even have to cast it to unit. Just drop `x` in on its own line of the do block, and the typechecker will complain (for example, in this case) that it doesn't have type `IO a`

Answer (score 12):

There is a hacky way:

```
main = do
       x <- something
       foo x
```

where `foo` is any old function which *doesn't* take an argument of the type you think `x` might be.  You'll get a nice error from GHC which includes the type expected by `foo` *and the type actually passed in*.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the GHCi Debugger:

```
> ghci a.hs
GHCi, version 7.0.4: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Loading package ffi-1.0 ... linking ... done.
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( a.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> :break 4
Breakpoint 0 activated at a.hs:4:8-14
*Main> :main
Stopped at a.hs:4:8-14
_result :: IO String = _
[a.hs:4:8-14] *Main> :list
3  main = do
4    x <- getLine
          ^^^^^^^
5    return x
[a.hs:4:8-14] *Main> :step
asd
Stopped at a.hs:5:3-10
_result :: IO String = _
x :: String = _
[a.hs:5:3-10] *Main> :t x
x :: String
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no easy way to do this. If your `something` function is in the global scope, you can check the type of that function. If it really is in your main function, its type is going to be `IO SomeType`, where `SomeType` is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is [Scion](https://github.com/nominolo/scion) which is basically an external wrapper over the GHC api which acts as a server providing IDE-like capabilities for editors like Emacs and Vim.

In the readme, it mentions the "experimental" command `C-c C-t` which shows the type of the identifier at point, including local identifiers. However, this will only work if your file type-checks.

This lets you find out the type of a local declaration without compiling your file or loading into GHCi, which means it won't disrupt your flow of thought as much.

Answer (score 2):

This is sort of the obvious non-answer. Given a local binding of the form

```
x <- something
```

In order to know the type of `x`, you merely need to know the type of `something`. Given `something` has the type `m a` (for some Monad `m`), `x` must therefore have the type `a`.

Comment: Yes, this is undeniably true, but sometimes it gets a little complicated.  It's nice to be able to check directly.

Comment: A bit late to the party, but I think this is only deniably true. There may be other code which constrains the type of `x`; for example, in `do { x <- undefined; putStrLn x }`, we know `x :: String` even though `String` does not appear in the type of `undefined`, even after specializing it to an `IO` type.